# What does fopen() return to the file pointer if file is opened?

Tags: c, file-pointer

For example if we declare a file pointer `fp` and open a file like this:
`FILE* fp = fopen("filename","w");`

If the file doesn't open `fopen` returns `NULL` to file pointer `fp`. What is stored in the file pointer `fp` if the file opens?

Comment: If `fopen` succeeds it will return a non-null pointer to a `FILE` structure. The `FILE` structure is an [*opaque data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), a black box of unknown contents. All you need to know is if the pointer was `NULL` or not (as documented in just about all books, tutorials and references).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C Committee draft N1570 states this about `FILE*`:

> **7.21.3 Files**
>   ...
>
> 6. The address of the `FILE` object used to control a stream may be signiﬁcant; a copy of a `FILE` object need not serve in place of the original.

The pointer returned by `fopen()` points to a `FILE` structure and the contents of that structure are implementation-specific (which means they are different in different platforms).

Even if you know the contents of that structure in a specific implementation, **you should NOT try to access any of its members or write code that depends on your knowledge of those members** (even if it were possible to do such a thing).

Comment: Note that it need not even be a pointer to something; it's just a resource handle representable in a pointer type. For example it could be `(FILE *)(idx+1)` where `idx` is a small integer into a table of open files.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page of [fopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

> Upon successful completion `fopen()`  return  a
>          `FILE` pointer.  Otherwise, `NULL` is returned and `errno` is set to indicate
>          the error.

*what is stored in the file pointer if the file opens ?* `fopen()` returns the `FILE` structure which is nothing but alias name of structure `_IO_FILE`

```
/* The opaque type of streams.  This is the definition used elsewhere.  */
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE; /* FILE is nothing but a structure which is _IO_FILE */
```

you can find above information in Linux headers `stdio.h`. And information about what `struct_IO_FILE` contains can be find in `libio.h` in Linux machine which is platform specific i.e it varies according to platform, It looks like below(open `/usr/include/libio.h` in terminal) on Linux platform.

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;           /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

Comment: That, of course, is merely one implementation — other implementations do it differently.  On a Mac, `_IO_FILE` only appears in a C++ header (`<streambuf>` as it happens), and then only in a comment.